# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.delegate

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new to Asp.net Core MVC. I have a view with validations from which I call a partial view using Jquery and ajax. The partial view displays correctly but the vaidation is not working in the partial view. Its throws up the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.delegate'

Posting my code here
Main view - Create.cshtml

```
@model InventoryModule.Models.Masters.Ledger

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Ledger</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" asp-antiforgery="true" id="fromLedger">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LedgerGroupId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="LedgerGroupId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.LedgerGroupId">
                <option value="0">--Select Group--</option>

            </select>
            <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="ModalCreate">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Create Product Group</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body" id="modelPartial">



                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnModel">
                New Group
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LedgerName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LedgerName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LedgerName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input asp-for="IsActive" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActive)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div>
     <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnModel").click(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'Get',
            url: '@(Url.Action("ShowPartial","Ledger"))',
            success: function (respose) {
                $('#modelPartial').html(respose);
                $('#ModalCreate').modal('show');
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
})
</script>
@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

--Partial View - _create.cshtml

```
@model InventoryModule.Models.Masters.LedgerGroup
@{
  string id = ViewData["id"]?.ToString() ?? "0";
}


<h4>LedgerGroup</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" id="formLG" asp-antiforgery="true">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LedgerGroupName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LedgerGroupName" id="LGName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LedgerGroupName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @*<input type="submit" asp-route-id=@id value="Create" asp-controller="LedgerGroup" class="btn btn-default" />*@
            <input type="button" id="submit1" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#submit1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.enable = false;
       //debugger;
       var ledgerGroup = $('#LedgerGroupName').val();

        var addAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            return data;
        };
var data = addAntiForgeryToken({ "LedgergrouId": 0, "LedgerGroupName": ledgerGroup, "id": @id});
        //alert(data);
       // debugger;
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@(Url.Action("CreateGroup","LedgerGroup"))',
                datatype: 'json',
                data: data,

                success: function(result) {

                   var groupName = result.ledgerGroupName;
                   var groupId = result.ledgerGroupId;;
                    alert(result);
                    //alert(groupId);
                    $('#LedgerGroupName').val('');


                    //Add it to the select list in Product Create Ledgergroup Dropdown.
                    $('#LedgerGroupId').append(new Option(groupName, groupId));
                     $('#LedgerGroupId').val(groupId);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Failed");
                }


    });

    });
});
```